# Update map background onclick tab button

Tags: bootstrap-4, tabs, openlayers, nav

I am using Bootstrap4 Nav tabs. As shown in the image, On click Tab4 button, I am only getting a blank map with zoom button but the map is not loaded. [image]

Can anyone suggest how to load map on tab click.
 I have tried with the below code -

```
 <div id="map4" class="map"></div>

  $('a[href="#tab4"]').one("click", function() {    
        var map4 = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
              new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
              })
            ],
            target: 'map4',
            view: new ol.View({
              center: [0, 0],
              zoom: 2
            })
          });

         map4.updateSize();
    });
```

Also I tried the following code -

```
document.getElementById('tab4').onclick = function() {  
map4.getTargetElement().hidden = false;
// map resize
map4.updateSize();
map4.render();
map4.renderSync();
};
```

This code loads the map background on tab click but I want that to load on tab button click.
I am using openlayers 4.

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: What version of OpenLayers are you using?  Does your map `<div>` have a size?  Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: I am using OpenLayers 4. Yes, <div> has a size defined in class="map" .